# How to wrap a single character inside an element in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am working for a book conversion where some entities are not supporting the font so i want to make that particular entities in a wrapper and handled these entities to change the font style:

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child1>This is simple para.</child1>
    <child1>This is &#x02bf; para.</child1>
    <child1>This is simple para.</child1>
    <child1>This is ʿ para.</child1>
</root>
```

**CURRENT OUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<root>
    <child1>This is simple para.</child1>
    <child1>
      <emph cstyle="Phonetic" type="Phonetic">This is &#x2bf; para.</emph>
   </child1>
    <child1>This is simple para.</child1>
    <child1>
      <emph cstyle="Phonetic" type="Phonetic">This is &#x2bf; para.</emph>
   </child1>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<root>
    <child1>This is simple para.</child1>
    <child1>This is <emph cstyle="Phonetic" type="Phonetic">&#x2bf;</emph> para.</child1>
    <child1>This is simple para.</child1>
    <child1>This is <emph cstyle="Phonetic" type="Phonetic">&#x2bf;</emph> para.</child1>
</root>
```

**WORKING XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="US-ASCII"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//text()[contains(normalize-space(.), '&#x02bf;')]">
        <emph cstyle="Phonetic" type="Phonetic">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </emph>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Solved by this way: <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([&#x02bf;|&#x002a;|&#x2013;]+)">
            
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <emph cstyle="Phonetic" type="Phonetic"><xsl:value-of select="."/></emph>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            
        </xsl:analyze-string>       
    </xsl:template>